# How to upgrade this code from tensorflow 1 to tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following piece of code:

```
    def _separable_conv(features, depth, kernel_size, depth_multiplier,
                        regularize_depthwise, rate, stride, scope):
      if activation_fn_in_separable_conv:
        activation_fn = tf.nn.relu
      else:
        activation_fn = None
        features = tf.nn.relu(features)
      return separable_conv2d_same(features,
                                   depth,
                                   kernel_size,
                                   depth_multiplier=depth_multiplier,
                                   stride=stride,
                                   rate=rate,
                                   activation_fn=activation_fn,
                                   regularize_depthwise=regularize_depthwise,
                                   scope=scope)
    for i in range(3):
      residual = _separable_conv(residual,
                                 depth_list[i],
                                 kernel_size=3,
                                 depth_multiplier=1,
                                 regularize_depthwise=regularize_depthwise,
                                 rate=rate*unit_rate_list[i],
                                 stride=stride if i == 2 else 1,
                                 scope='separable_conv' + str(i+1))
    if skip_connection_type == 'conv':
      shortcut = tf.Conv2D(inputs,
                             depth_list[-1],
                             [1, 1],
                             stride=stride,
                             activation_fn=None,
                             scope='shortcut')
      outputs = residual + shortcut
    elif skip_connection_type == 'sum':
      outputs = residual + inputs
    elif skip_connection_type == 'none':
      outputs = residual
    else:
      raise ValueError('Unsupported skip connection type.')

    return slim.utils.collect_named_outputs(outputs_collections,
                                            sc.name,
                                            outputs)
```

In the last line, we're using the slim module from tf.contrib, which is deprecated in tensorflow 2. What functions exist in tensorflow 2 or otherwise to do the same function as the slim.utils.collect_named_outputs line?

Comment: Best approach is to import tensorflow2 as tf, run the code check the errors and fix them.

Comment: I'd give a shot at running their update script first.  
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

TF-slim is now available as an external package on [Github](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim), and it has support for Tensorflow 2. The library has the same exact functionality (including this method!), it just has a new home and a different way to install.

There is no Tensorflow 2 code in the core libraries that can directly replace your code.